# Modal pop up for check box

Tags: c#, asp.net, modalpopupextender

I have  a modal pop up panel and  a  check box  in that panel. I have  set   check box `autopostback` property `true`. When I  check mark the  check box the panel disappears.

I want the  panel still to be there when check box  clicked  because  I have  code for `oncheckedchanged`. I also have 2 buttons. If any one  is  clicked, the panel disappears. I tried with `OnClientClick="JavaScript: return false;"`  for the button, but the `buton_clicked` event does not work for the  button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if checking/unchecking the checkbox changes the UI in the popup panel, use ajax postback to only reload the content of the panel or the updated controls instead of the whole page. Therefore your popup panel will stay there. If it simply do some processing on code behind and does not change UI, consider using webmethod and $.ajax() call.

the same concept goes to your buttons.